# Is there a function in R to aggregate rows with same values in some columns but different in others?

Tags: r

My db example:

```
      n_historia fecha      hemo_detalle                                                                  
  <chr>      <date>     <chr>                                                                         
1 1155148    2020-11-01 Serratia marcescens
2 1155148    2020-11-06 Klebsiella
3 1155148    2020-11-06 NEGATIVO
```

Expected output:

```
  n_historia fecha.x      hemo_detalle.x       fecha.y     hemo_detalle.y  fecha.z     hemo_detalle.z                                                              
  <chr>      <date>       <chr>                <date>      <chr>           <date>      <chr>                                                              
1 1155148    2020-11-01   Serratia marcescens  2020-11-06  Klebsiella      2020-11-06  NEGATIVO
```

Thanks for any help you can offer.

**Reproducible sample data**

```
structure(list(n_historia = c(1155148, 1155148, 1155148), fecha = c("2020-11-01", 
"2020-11-06", "2020-11-06"), hemo_detalle = c("Serratia marcescens", 
"Klebsiella", "NEGATIVO")), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: I've not used r, but from your output looks vaguely like a pivot table. You may need a grouping column to force into the columns (assuming pivot and you want to group the results.
Might be worth searching for that option in r?
Also, pivot wont work on the date column as that would end up as two lines (one for each date).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use :

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  group_by(n_historia) %>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = row, values_from = c(fecha, hemo_detalle)) %>%
  ungroup

#  n_historia fecha_1    fecha_2    fecha_3    hemo_detalle_1     hemo_detalle_2 hemo_detalle_3
#       <int> <chr>      <chr>      <chr>      <chr>              <chr>          <chr>         
#1    1155148 2020-11-01 2020-11-06 2020-11-06 Serratiamarcescens Klebsiella     NEGATIVO
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked perfectly, now I have to deepen pivot tables.

Answer (score 0):

We could use `rowid`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(data.table)
df %>%
    mutate(row = rowid(n_historia)) %>%   
    pivot_wider(names_from = row, values_from = c(fecha, hemo_detalle)) %>%
    ungroup
```